# Difficulty updating an existing subdocument's array element with Mongoose using 'set'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, model-view-controller

I am not able to save & update a Mongoose subdocument's array element using the set function.

**Brief**
I use a front end HTML form that creates a request eventually calling this controller in my Node Express REST API. The req.body parameter being passed into the controller is an object matching the structure of an element of the purchaseOrders array. I successfully GET the element, modify it in a pretty form on the front end, then POST to an app level controller which then creates a PUT request into my API controller (API controller function below).

**Problem**
I can't seem to use the set method on an element of the array I'm targetting. Secondly, if I use a direct assignment instead, I get a save error.

When I use

```
customer[0].purchaseOrders[0] = req.body
```

I receive a type error

```
TypeError: purchaseOrderRaw.save is not a function
```

and if I use the set method

```
customer[0].purchaseOrders[0].set(req.body)
```

I receive a different type error

```
TypeError: purchaseOrderRaw[0].purchaseOrders[0].set is not a function
```

Please note, my goal is not to assign each field individually. Ideally, I would like to use the set method so that I can pass the req.body directly into the array. **What am I doing wrong?**

Here is the Document returned by Mongoose using the aggregate framework. I'm basically trying to update the first element in the purchaseOrders array.

{
"customerID":1,
"purchaseOrders":[
{
"_id":"5eee249ac534edf5d09ed036",
"purchaseOrderID":450012321
}
]
}

The controller in my REST API. I've removed a lot of error handling for brevity.

```
const Customer = mongoose.model('Customer');
const purchaseOrderUpdate = (req, res) => {
    Customer
        .aggregate()
        .match({customerID:req.params.customerID})
        .project({_id:0, customerID:1, purchaseOrders: {
                $filter: {
                    input: '$purchaseOrders',
                    as: 'purchaseOrders',
                    cond: { $eq: ['$$purchaseOrders.purchaseOrderID', req.params.purchaseOrderID]}
                }}})
        .exec((err, customer) => {
            customer[0].purchaseOrders[0].set(req.body);
            customer.save(); // excluded the callback for brevity
        });
}
```